# How to make a command completely empty / invisible / non-existent?

Tags: spacing, macros

I have a command like

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{#1}
```

which I sometimes replace by:

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{}
```

In terms of spacing/whitespace, the behavior of the "empty" command is as follows:

```
Test.

\todo{foo} % does not generate (vertical) whitespace => good

Test\todo{foo}. Test. % does not generate (horizontal) whitespace => good

Test\todo{foo}. \todo{foo} Test. % _does_ generate (horizontal) whitespace => bad
```

Is there any way to avoid this, i.e., to (temporarily) replace a command in a way so that it is *fully equivalent* to removing all occurrences of the command?

(I know that there are packages like todonotes or verbatim, which provide similar functionality. But I always wanted to know how to solve this manually, and never had an idea how to approach this / what to search for. Using `\xspace` or `\empty` in the command did not work at least.)

Comment: Related: [How to define commands that do not consume any space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130012/5764)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The classical way is using `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`. They are used by `\label` or `\index`, both supposed to be invisible/empty regarding spacing.
These commands remember, if there is a space *before* the command. If yes, the second space afterwards is suppressed by `\ignorespaces`. The commands are defined in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\@bsphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \@savsk\lastskip
    \@savsf\spacefactor
  \fi}
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi}
```

Applied to `\todo`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test.

\todo{foo}

Test\todo{foo}. Test.

Test\todo{foo}. \todo{foo} Test.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Limitation:** The method can fail, if the macros using `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` are used one after each other. The second `\@bsphack` does not know the state of the previous one. Therefore `\ignorespaces` can be suppressed leaving the following space.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Apparently, the occurrence of a command will internally never be equivalent to the case of a "non-occurrence". So I guess the best solution here is to emulate the non-occurrence.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't really generate space it's just that you have added two spaces, you would see same from `a {} b` with one space before and one after. But you can end your command with `\ignorespaces` to ignore the following space.

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\ignorespaces}
```

Comment: This is looking good, but: In this case `Test\todo{foo}.\todo{foo} Test.` behaves "unexpected", since it is not the same as `Test\todo{foo}. Test.` -- any idea to solve this as well?

Comment: @bluenote10 `\ignorespaces` is simpler, the more complicated thing is to see if there was a space before and just ignorespaces in that case) that's what the latex `\@bspack` macro does (it is used in `\label{}` and `\index{]` and similar commands that are supposed to be "invisible"). I thought I'd just do the simple one, but if you want the other, give the tick to Heiko:-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Considering the educational aspect of my question, your answer is highly appreciated :).

Answer (score 6):

You put nothing into the horizontal/vertical list when `\toto` is empty. Thus the `\spacefactor` manipulating is redundant (see the accepted answer). The following code is sufficient for this task:

```
\def\hideme{\ifdim\lastskip>0pt \ignorespaces\fi}
\def\todo#1{#1}
% or:
\def\todo#1{\hideme}
```